# Microsoft Deployment Toolkit versus Thick image + GPOs

Tags: windows, group-policy, deployment, imaging, mdt

I know that MDT/WDS combo is very useful in creating thin images and deploying OSes, applications, drivers, etc. as needed with said image.

I was wondering though is it worth it to learn MDT if one could create a thick image with some complex applications and configurations baked in and push the remainder of applications with GPO?

Why would I use MDT if I could achieve the same with GPOs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many advantages to using MDT over standard imaging / WDS deployments. Depending on your scenario, simply creating an image with preloaded software and using GPO to finish it off, may be sufficient. But, if you're regularly deploying new systems, working with a lot of varied machine types, or would like to include user state migration then MDT is the way to go.

The largest drawback for me without MDT is that the images go stale very quickly, and are so specific in nature that you could wind up having to maintain several different sets of images.

Here are a few things MDT has over the other options:

- advanced scripting capabilities to tightly control the deployment based on all types of variables
- use state migration capabilities built in so you can capture, reload, and restore data and settings.
- multi site deployments where pulling an image over a WAN is not optimal.
- zero touch deployments
- windows update so your images are always deployed fully patched
- a lite touch deployment that allows you to interactively customize several components of the deployment like data backup, product key, domain join, admin password, which applications to install, etc.
- automatic selection of all aspects of the deployment based on machine types and other variables so the deployment is customized for a specific machine.
- a sophisticated driver database that can be maintained independently of the images.
- an application database that can be maintained independently of the images.

This is just some of the things I can think of off the top of my head.  Using the features of MDT you can automate the maintenance of base images, capture data when necessary, always deploy with proper drivers and all patches applied, and fully customize things that can't take place after deployment like the default user profile.

In my opinion, any long term deployment strategy should include MDT. And, apart from the bugs and broken code that seems to come with the territory, MDT is really not that hard to learn.